# Crystal Reports 9.0 .rpt to Excel

Tags: .net, excel, crystal-reports, vb6, crystal-reports-9

Earlier i had repeated page headers in a single excel sheet. I suppressed the page header and page footer after the first page. After suppressing the alignment of some columns values changes from the line where the first page ends and values are not getting populated continuously when i see the excel report at column level. Can someone please help me out in doing the alignment so that all the column values are in one single column and half set not getting shifted to next column.

Comment: Your verbal description is hard to follow - a picture is word a thousand words.

Comment: That is very boring. You have to perfectly align field in the designer. Try to set the "GridSize" and "EnableSnapToGrid" property of the "Report", use the "Align" and "Size" commands to grant your fields are really aligned and have the same size (per column), leave no empty space between columns and rows.